# Compose from arbitrary folder with files in build context and Dockerfile folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'd like to compose a service while keeping the file structure of my project neat. But Docker appears to have issues with paths outside the build context. I'm creating a package and would like to keep all Docker related stuff in a folder under the project root. But I can't find a way to reference the project files from `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile`. When creating the containers files from the project must be copied.

Here's my current project structure:

```
root/
    docker/
        docker-compose.yml
        Dockerfile
        docker_resource.txt
        config
    src/
        project-files.whatever
    root-files.txt
```

Now if I `$cd docker` and `$docker-compose up`, there are two possibilities that I've tried. Either my Dockerfile copies the files with `COPY .. /path/in/container` or the compose file has build instructions like:

```
x-build: &my-build
    context: ..
    dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

The first approach doesn't work. Apparently Dockerfile cannot reference anything outside the build context. The second approach appears to work, but only after I edit my copy command from `docker_resource.txt` to `docker/docker_resource.txt`. Ideally I'd like to retain the ability to `docker build` from `./docker` *and* keep the things clean - not having to worry about the composing context in the Dockerfile. Is this possible?

Minimally I'm after a way to have docker related files in an arbitrary folder and to be able to specify the build context in the compose file without additional changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to treat `src/project-files.whatever` like a self-sufficient minimal build. I would put a Dockerfile inside src. It should be treated as part of the project, and should be specific to it. You would still need to edit your copy command though.

```
root/
    docker/
        docker-compose.yml
        docker_resource.txt
        config
    src/
        project-files.whatever
        Dockerfile
    root-files.txt
```

You want to separate your compose and Dockerfile and resources anyway. Depending on what is inside `docker_resource`you may want to move it into src. Think the image as the program itself, with no configuration. I suggest putting resource / config stuff in a volume so that you wouldn't have to rebuild from scratch with every change.

Another way to do it is to put Dockerfile one level above and allow your root to be the build context. Your structure would be something like this in that case:

```
/root
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    docker_resource.txt
    config
    src/
        project-files.whatever
    root-Files/
        root-files.txt
```

Not sure if you like that.

Comment: Don't like it, but that doesn't help much. Regardless, thanks for the answer! I'll consider the first approach you laid out.